# Porting JavaME to Android

Tags: java, android, java-me, j2ab

I am trying to port an app from javaME to Android.
I have a part where graphics class is used.

I have used J2ME Android bridge (http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/j2ab/Converting_From_J2ME/8) to gain access to Graphics class. Im still missing some of the methods such as:

- getStrokeStyle()
- setStrokeStyle()
- drawRGB()
- fillTriangle()

Also how do i use Vector?

example: `Vector polylines = g.getPolylines();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an automatic J2ME->Android convertor in our company. Mapping J2ME graphics (javax.microedition.ldcui.Graphics) to Android graphics (android.graphics.Canvas) is really easy.

setStrokeStyle - change path effect on your Paint instance

```
PathEffect EFFECT_DOTTED_STROKE = new DashPathEffect(new float[] {2, 4}, 4);

if (style == SOLID) {
    strokePaint.setPathEffect(null);
}
else {
    strokePaint.setPathEffect(EFFECT_DOTTED_STROKE);
}
```

drawRGB - directly calling a Canvas method

```
public void drawRGB(int[] rgbData, int offset, int scanLength, int x, int y, int width, int height, boolean processAlpha) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(rgbData, offset, width, x + translateX, y + translateY, width, height, processAlpha, null);
}
```

fillTriangle - using a path

```
public void fillTriangle(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int x3, int y3) {
    Path path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(x1 + translateX, y1 + translateY);
    path.lineTo(x2 + translateX, y2 + translateY);
    path.lineTo(x3 + translateX, y3 + translateY);
    path.close();

    strokePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    canvas.drawPath(path, strokePaint);
}
```

By Vector you mean java.util.Vector? Android API contains exactly the same class...

Answer (score 1):

you can draw shapes by overwriting the onDraw method in a layout 
for example

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawCircle(cx, cy, radius, paint)
}
```